# How to find a line with word A and not word B using Visual Studio 2017 Regular Expression

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I cannot figure out how to Find in Files a line that has "dim" and does not have " as ".

I opened Find in Files, set checkmark Use Reg Exp, set the file types, but can't figure out how to get:   dim AND NOT as

Purpose is to locate any 'dim' that is not explicitly declared, because I'm converting a 20,000 line VB project to C#.

Comment: Don't have VS2017 myself, but can't you get a list of all variable defined in the code and see what type they are? Those that don't have "As" are implicitly defined.

Comment: Untested, by try this: `Dim [^\s\=]+\s*(?!As)`

Comment: VV: didn't work.  Still gets lines with dim and as, and lines with dim and no as.